# Apache: proper content-type for CSS

Tags: css, apache

I have a CSS file which locally gives me an error saying that it is 'text/html' and fails to load.  But on the server it is 'text/css' and works fine.    The CSS file validates.

How can I get my local Apache (2.4.23) to recognize it as a 'text/css' file?

I've tried modifying .htaccess:

```
<Files *.css>
    ForceType text/css
</Files>
```

I've got mime_module enabled.

I also tried:

```
AddType text/css .css
```

For instance this basic css file is recognized as 'text/html':

```
#map:hover { cursor: pointer; }

#map5:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```